# c++ struct value appears to change on it's own

Tags: c++, data-structures, segmentation-fault

I'm running just a simple code, but I keep getting "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)"
Doing some debugging, I found that the value of edges[0].start somehow becomes -2147483644. I'm finding this behavior quite hard to explain and still trying to find where did I get it wrong but I don't even update any edges values! Anyways, whatever hints you can give me will be greatly valued. You will find the code bellow.
Thanks in advance!
Warm wishes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <climits>
#include "Utils.h"

struct edge {
    int start;
    int end;
    int weight;
};

int main() {
    int n = 4;
    int m = 4;
    edge edges[4] = {
            {2,4,5},
            {4,1,6},
            {1,3,8},
            {3,2,-3}
    };
    int v,e;
    int distance[4];
    // Step 1: initialize graph
    for(v = 0; v < n; v++){
        distance[v] = INT_MAX;
    }
    distance[0] = 0; //source

    // Step 2: relax edges repeatedly
    for(v = 0; v < n; v++){
        for(e = 0; e < m; e++){
            if(distance[edges[e].start] + edges[e].weight < distance[edges[e].end] ){ //relax
                distance[edges[e].end] = distance[edges[e].start] + edges[e].weight;
            }
        }
    }
    // Step 3: check for negative-weight cycles
    for(e = 0; e < m; e++) {
        if (distance[edges[e].start] + edges[e].weight < distance[edges[e].end]) { //shouldn't be able to relax
            std::cout << "Negative cycle detected, please declare war to Paraguay";
        }
    }
    for(v = 0; v < n; v++){
        std::cout << distance[v] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Valid indexes into `distance` are 0 through 3. `edges[e].start` and `edges[e].end` have values of 4. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of a buffer overrun.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'n' and 'm' iterator variables are defined as 4, yet the 'edges' array has indexes between 0 and 3 inclusive. Your loop will try to access edges[4], resulting in an index out of range and undefined behaviour, which is the likely cause of your start value corruption.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined distance variable with size of 4

```
int distance[4];
```

While the values of edge array are:

```
 edge edges[4] = {
            {2,4,5},
            {4,1,6},
            {1,3,8},
            {3,2,-3}
    };
```

You are using value of `edge structure` to access the cell of each `distance array.`
The value of edge ranges from -3 to 8 while the value of distance ranges from 0 to 3; This will cause the buffer overflow and will cause application to crash.

Comment: A crash isn't guaranteed, it's simply undefined behavior. Anything can happen, from appearing to work properly to [demons flying from your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: I test it with ranges between 0 and 3 and still getting error, in the first comparison `edges[0].start` become `-2147483647`

Answer (score -1):

I'm actually don't know why, but this works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

struct edge {
    int start;
    int end;
    int weight;
};

int main() {
    int n = 4;
    int m = 4;

    const edge edges[4] = {
            {2,4,5},
            {4,1,6},
            {1,3,8},
            {3,2,-3}
    }; /* <= for my surprise, I'm not get error with this
        *    for indexes of distance[something]
        */
    int v,e;
    int distance[4];
    // Step 1: initialize graph
    for(v = 0; v < n; v++){
        distance[v] = 214748364; // <== with this get fixed
    }
    distance[0] = 0; //source

    // Step 2: relax edges repeatedly
        for(v = 0; v < n; v++){
            for(e = 0; e < m; e++){
                if(distance[edges[e].start] + edges[e].weight < distance[edges[e].end] ){ //relax
                    distance[edges[e].end] = distance[edges[e].start] + edges[e].weight;
                }
            }
        }
        // Step 3: check for negative-weight cycles
        for(e = 0; e < m; e++) {
            if (distance[edges[e].start] + edges[e].weight < distance[edges[e].end]) { //shouldn't be able to relax
                std::cout << "Negative cycle detected, please declare war to Paraguay";
            }
        }
        for(v = 0; v < n; v++){
            std::cout << distance[v] << std::endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of use `distance[v] = INT_MAX;` simply use `distance[v] = 214748364;` or something not so close of `INT_MAX` and I get this output:

```
0
8
13
16
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Comment: I realize some more test and get the closest value to `INT_MAX` that works for assign to distance is `INT_MAX - 5` or `2147483642`, more than that `edges[0].start` will get the negative value assigned

Comment: Why downvote without any explanation, if got with the problem and offer a solution?